# Proper way to add jquery packages to an Angular 10+ project?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, npm, package

I am trying to install `jquery` and `jquery-slimscroll` packages to an Angular project (version > 10), but the packages are not seems to be installed properly. So, regarding to this issue, could you please clarify me about the following issues below?

Assume that I have the following client structure:

```
ClientApp ---
            |--- node_modules
            |--- package.json
            |--- angular.json
```

**1.** What is the proper way to add `jquery` and `jquery-slimscroll` to the project?

Should I run `npm install` on the ClientApp folder? Or is there a better way for the latest Angular versions?

**2.** I think there are several ways to add these packages as script like the following:

in `angular.json`:

```
"scripts": [
  ".../jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
  ".../jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.js",
]
```

Is it not a good approach to add them like this? Should I add them in npm as in the 1st question?

**3.** What about the `packages.json`?  Some packages are added to `packages.json` instead of `angular.json`. What is the difference and why some packages are added another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have to understand the function of `angular.json` and `package.json`.

[Angular.json](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config)

> A file named angular.json at the root level of an Angular workspace
> provides workspace-wide and project-specific configuration defaults
> for build and development tools provided by the Angular CLI. Path
> values given in the configuration are relative to the root workspace
> folder.

[Package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/configuring-npm/package-json#description)

> Initially, this package.json includes a starter set of packages, some
> of which are required by Angular and others that support common
> application scenarios. You add packages to package.json as your
> application evolves. You may even remove some.
>
> The package.json is organized into two groups of packages:
>
> Dependencies are essential to running applications. DevDependencies
> are only necessary to develop applications.

So, for the questions of the proper way to add these jquery dependencies, you can do both, the `npm install jquery` or add to the package.json and if needed to the angular.json.

The difference of both ways is that if you use `npm install jquery` it will add the dependencies automatically and download the packages to your `node_modules`, you add it manually, you will need to run `npm install` anyway, tp get the packages.

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed explanations, voted up ;) I need to be clarified about the following issue. Could you explain these points one by one please?

Comment: **1.** What are the changes after installing a package e.g. using `npm install jquery`? Will it add the dependencies to only `package.json`? Or will also add `angular.json` as well?

Comment: **2.** Do we add to `angular.json` file only css and js files? May any installed package reference be added automatically to this file?

Comment: **3.** I think I can use jquery by just adding the js reference to only adding scripts section in the `angular.json` file. The difference between adding this manually to that file and installing jquery via npm install is that: when using npm install, the related files and folders of jquery is downloaded to node_modules and the package reference is added to package.json. **Is that true?**

Comment: 1 - Yes, all the dependencies will be added into `package.json`.

Comment: 2 - the package will only be referenced on `angular.json` if it change something on angular configuration, like, build configurations, asset configurations, optimization configurations, styles and scripts configurations and so on.

Comment: 3 - You will need to get the packages, otherwise it won't work. And yes, it's true.

Comment: Many thanks. Regarding to your comment "*You will need to get the packages, otherwise it won't work.*", I am not sure if it is always true. Because sometimes I think it is possible to use the single javascript file by just adding the reference to angular.json and we do not have to install it (e.g. jquery-slimscroll) as a package in npm. Because for example jquery-slimscroll, the only we need is a javascript file. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yeah, you can do it like this, because basically this is what the packages do. The only difference is that when you get the packages, you don't need to access a URL everytime you run the script.